# The trapezoid rule and the integral: $\displaystyle\int_1^4(x-1)(x-4)\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I've tried this many times, and the result I get is always $-4$, I don't know why..
I first get $h$, $ (4-1)/6 $ , then I put $h/2(x)$, $x = 2(-2) + 2(-2)$, which is equal to $1/2(-8) = -4$, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

> $\displaystyle\int_1^4(x-1)(x-4)\,\mathrm dx\qquad$Use $6$ strips.$\qquad$Area $\approx\color{grey}{\boxed{\color{black}{-4}\,}}$ sq. un.

Comment: I suppose a *tule* is something between a *rule* and a *tool*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you found that $h=\dfrac{4-1}{6} = \dfrac{1}{2}$, then for $\color{blue}{n=6}$ strips, the trapezoid rule tells you that

$$A \approx \frac{1}{4}\left[f(1) + 2f\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) + 2f(2) + 2f\left(\frac{5}{2}\right) + 2f(3) + 2f\left(\frac{7}{2}\right) + f(4)\right]$$

where $f(x)=(x-1)(x-4)$.  Evaluating this gives you

$$\begin{aligned} A &\approx \frac{1}{4}\left[0+ 2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(-\frac{5}{2}\right) + 2(1)(-2) + 2\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\left(-\frac{3}{2}\right)+2(2)(-1) + 2\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)+0\right] \\ &= \ldots\end{aligned}$$

Can you take things from here?

Comment: I did ( 1/4(0+2(-2)+2(-2)+0) and got -2, not sure if i'm missing something (i obviously am), please can you solve it?

Comment: @SamirChahine I updated my answer showing a little more work, but not giving the complete solution.  It should be clearer now as to what is missing from your solution.